# How to automatically load a given so into any newly-started process under Linux?

Tags: linux, dll, shared-libraries, code-injection

Under Windows, there are several ways to automatically load a given dll into any newly-started process.

Is it possible to do the same thing under Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the same thing under Linux?

There is `/etc/ld.so.preload`, but that only works for dynamically-linked program binaries. Documentation [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

You also need to be *extremely* careful: if you specify something that can't be preloaded, you may make your system unbootable, or you may no longer be able to log in.